# Position labels in radial charts - react-vis

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I am struggling with positioning labels in radial charts using the react-vis library. Here is my code:

```
const DonutChart = () => {
    const data = [{ angle: 4, label: "Yes" }, { angle: 4, label: "No" }, { angle: 4, label: "Dont know" }]
    return (
        <>
            <RadialChart
                data={data}
                width={300}
                height={300}
                innerRadius={68} 
                radius={100}
                showLabels={true}
                labelsStyle={{
                    fill: "red",
                    dominantBaseline:"middle",
                    textAnchor:"middle"
                }}
                padAngle={0.1}
            />
        </>
    ) }
```

To style the labels I am using labelsStyle as indicated in the documentation. With fill, the text color of the labels is indeed red. But the position doesn't change with setting the dominantBaseline and textAnchor.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSdxr.png)

Inspecting the console I see that different values are attributing to  which are children of  where my style is applied.

[Capture d’écran du 2022-05-13 12-17-20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR0G2.png)

How should I change that ?

Thank you